# Разорвало вёрстку на странице метки

Tags: дефект, адаптивный-дизайн

См. приложенную картинку:

[image: ПОТРАЧЕНО]

Ссылка на страницу: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlite.

Окружение: Ubuntu 16.04, Firefox 62, Firefox 63.

Comment: Предлагается баги по адаптивному дизайну скидывать как ответы под одним вопросом, который я предложил как дубликат. Там уже есть этот случай. Или можно сразу писать на MSE.